# Whats the simplest MAKEFILE I could have the works for a single C file?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, makefile

I have a file called "main.c".  Whats the simplest Makefile I can have to compile this file into an executable that I can run like `./blah`?

Comment: Please make some effort to do your homework before asking us. There's a reason your professor wants you to use a Makefile - so you can learn how to write Makefiles for more useful projects.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to upset the homework police.  I have tried Googling it, but the Makefile is obviously incredibly powerful, and can be extremely complex.  I admit Iw as having some troubles understanding much of it.  This subject isn't a programming subject, but the assessment requires C code to call native OS functions.  I've never touched C before, and this assignment is due in a couple of hours.  I was frustrated, and desperate and needed some help.  sorry If I upset you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
all:
     gcc -o blah main.c
```

You don't need makefile here, simple shell script is OK.

Comment: assignment sheet say we must include a Makefile.

Comment: When I used this and run `make` - it returns "Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: @Ash: The bit in front of `gcc` has to be a tab, not spaces. (You get that error if you use spaces.)

Comment: The target of the makefile rule should be `blah` not `all` as that is the name of the file that the command actually makes. Otherwise make won't calculate dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 11):

If you're running GNU Make and if you don't need to link in extra libraries, the simplest makefile is no makefile at all.  Try:

```
make main
```

If you don't want to have to specify `main`, then you can use the following one-line Makefile:

```
all: main
```

GNU Make has several implicit rules that it uses if you don't define them yourself.  The one that makes this work is something like:

```
%: %.c
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

For more info, see: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Implicit

Comment: Apparently the assignment requires that the output be `blah`, not `main`, so he will need a Makefile. The above is still useful information, but won't actually apply here.

Comment: If your executable should be called `blah` the easiest would be just to rename your source file to `blah.c` if this is permitted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `blah` does not seem to be a requirement, but rather an example: OP said " that I can run *like* `./blah`". So this one-liner `Makefile` seems fine

Answer (score 5):

```
all: blah
blah: main.c
    gcc main.c -o blah
```

Comment: I wrote and posted my answer before anything else shown, and I did not see the 'homework' tag. I agree with Chris Lutz; you'll get nowhere in life asking for help on such miserable assignments.

Comment: `all: blah` makes this less simple that it needs to be and may also break things if a file called `all` actually existed. Apart from this point, this is the best answer.

Comment: Actually, after further thought, in this simple case a file called `all` is probably not going to break the dependency checking; it's still redundant as make will treat the first target as the default target in any case.

Comment: I entirely agree with Charles about my offer not being the barest simplest possible but I went for this compromise because I found it a good balance between terseness and understandability. Make has already too much black magic I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest I would recommend is:

```
myprog: myprog.o
        $(CC) -o $@ @^
```

Via implicit rules, this will result in a separate step that compiles `myprog.c` to `myprog.o` before linking it. The reason I like this better than the other answer (by Arnaud) is that it scales to more source files without having to enlarge the makefile significantly:

```
myprog: myprog.o foo.o bar.o helper.o my.o your.o his.o her.o
        $(CC) -o $@ @^
```

Comment: Should that be `$^` instead of `@^`?

Answer (score 2):

As Jander said, if your source is a single file named `blah.c` you could use this to output an executable named `blah`:

```
all: blah
```

Or even:

```
blah:
```

Everything else is implicit when using GNU `make`

While this is extremely simple, it does have a few advantages over some of the more complex answers:

- Compiler is not hardcoded: let your environment choose `gcc` for you!
- Your program name is set only once, a good DRY programming practice.
- Does not create intermediate `*.o` files which are not needed for this simple project.

That said, I strongly suggest you to improve your `Makefile` by adding at least `clean` and `all` rules and `-Wall` flags. This can be done with the following `Makefile`, still keeping all the above advantages:

```
TARGET=blah
CFLAGS=-Wall

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```